# Update XCEED Property Grid to Database

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

i have a task to update the values in the Xceed Property grid to Database. how can i achieve this. please help.  View code is mentioned below

```
enter code here

<xctk:PropertyGrid  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=OpenInfo}" 
SelectedObject="{Binding Path=SelectedProject}" ShowSortOptions="False" NameColumnWidth="100">

<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="PropertyValueChanged">
     <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay,  Path=SaveInfo}" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I am binding an object to the Property grid.  When the user updates the properties of the
object i need to update the changed property to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [Repository Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) in your application. The [ItemsSource](http://doc.xceedsoft.com/products/XceedWpfDataGrid/Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.v4.3~Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataGridForeignKeyDescription~ItemsSource.html) of the DataGridControl can be bound to a RepositoryView (which is a collection of RepositoryItems) in the ViewModel and the connection service is responsible of storing/retrieving the items to/from the database. It is a very bad habit to bind the DataGridControl directly to the database: it can get "out of sync" easily and you have little control over the data which is transferred between the client and the server. When using Repositories, you can have control over each item and know it's state (whether it should be updated on the database etc).